# Look and Feel without hard coded values

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, uimanager

Right now I set the LaF like this: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` It works fine and gives the look and feel I want to have. Sadly at some point in my code, I have to set some icons manually, because the automatical setting of those doesn't work properly (sets wrong icon). I currently have:

```
if (node.getAllowsChildren()) {
    setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("FileView.directoryIcon"));
}else {
    setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("FileView.fileIcon"));
}
```

but it doesn't use the LaF icons and I have no idea, on how to find the icons that look like the LaF. So my question is, is there an easy way to get lets say the LaF folder icon?

---

Design I currently get:

[image]

And the design I want to have:

[image]

Comment: 1) See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for use of good icons in a tree. It uses `FileSystemView` to discover the correct icons. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `UIDefaults` class to get the values:

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
Icon icon = (Icon)defaults.get(...);
```

Check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). This Icons change when the LAF is changed.

Comment: I changed to `setIcon(UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().getIcon("FileView.fileIcon"));` and it stays the same.

Comment: Did you follow the link and download the code and test it. The Icons change for me. Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I was able to identify the right key I need for the design. Very nice application